# Time.parse produces strange dates

Tags: ruby

Wondering what happened with these inputs that gave me something strange instead of `2013-05-31 13:30:00 -0400`

```
Time.parse("05-31 13:30") => 2013-06-06 16:30:00 -0400

Time.parse("5 31 13:30")  => 2013-07-01 13:30:00 -0400
```

Comment: `Time.parse("05/31 13:30") # => 2013-05-31 13:30:00 +0400` - I guess, your strings are just too weird for it to make sense.

Comment: Which locale? Maybe you're expecting some weird timezone transisions where you live?

Comment: I would expect `05-31 13:30` to give me `2013-05-31 13:30`, instead of "2013-06-06 16:30:00 -0400". Like where did the 6's even come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@SergioTulentsev's comment points to the problem. `Date.parse` can't know every possible combination of ways people might want to structure a date/datetime value. That's why Date supports [`strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime), which lets YOU define the pattern:

```
require 'date'
DateTime.strptime("05-31 13:30", '%m-%d %H:%M')
=> #<DateTime: 2013-05-31T13:30:00+00:00 ((2456444j,48600s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
DateTime.strptime("5 31 13:30", '%m %d %H:%M')
=> #<DateTime: 2013-05-31T13:30:00+00:00 ((2456444j,48600s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

The problem then becomes one of which format string to use for a given date string. In this test I changed the second datetime string so it's more obvious that the code is working correctly:

```
require 'date'
DATE_PATTERNS = {
  /[0-2]\d-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}/  => '%m-%d %H:%M',
  /[0-2]?\d \d{1,2} \d{2}:\d{2}/ => '%m %d %H:%M'
}

puts ["05-31 13:30", "5 31 13:31"].map { |str|
  pattern = DATE_PATTERNS.keys.find { |k|
    str[k]
  }
  puts pattern.source
  DateTime.strptime(str[pattern], DATE_PATTERNS[pattern]).to_s
}
```

Which outputs:

```
[0-2]\d-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}
[0-2]?\d \d{1,2} \d{2}:\d{2}
2013-05-31T13:30:00+00:00
2013-05-31T13:31:00+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

In your time-string the year is missing. 
parse tries to fix this but fails.

With the year given - like so

```
Time.parse("2013-05-31 13:30")
```

parse works.